# How to convert a string version of a number array in json to a number array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following **json object**:

var data = [{"name":"abc", "count":"[20.8, 100]"},
             {"name":"xyz", "count":"[40, 100]"}]

Notice the array in double quotes : "[20.8, 100]"

I want the double quotes to go

**Expected Output:**

var data = [{"name":"abc", "count":[20.8, 100]},
             {"name":"xyz", "count":[40, 100]}]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and assign the value to the same property.

```js
var data = [{"name":"abc", "count":"[20.8, 100]"}, {"name":"xyz", "count":"[40, 100]"}];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.count = JSON.parse(a.count);
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Iterate the JSON using javaScript [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

**Step 2 :** Use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the JSON string(**`"[20.8, 100]"`**) into JSON object(**`[20.8, 100]`**).

**Working demo :**

```js
var data = [
             {"name":"abc", "count":"[20.8, 100]"}, 
             {"name":"xyz", "count":"[40, 100]"}
           ];

for (var i in data) {
  data[i].count = JSON.parse(data[i].count);
}

console.log(data);
```